# How do i read a multi-line string from properties file in protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have an SFTP server to connect to which there is a ppk file. 
To automate this, I am giving the ppk value directly as a String in the properties file. 
I tired to give '\n \', '\n', \ at the end of each line.
No matter what I try, only the first line of the ppk file is fetched by the code. 
Is there some way where I can automate this part without hard coding it in the program?

```
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var properties = PropertiesReader('./environment.properties');
console.log(properties.get('Encrypted_Key'));
```

Here is the sample ppk key i gave in the file environment.properties

```
Encrypted_Key =-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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```

Comment: It's hard to suggest something without seeing a code. Please share what you have tried

Comment: @YuriyGerasimovich Edited the question to add more details. Please let me know if you can help me on this! Thanks

Comment: Put all the text on one line and just put a `\n` where you would typically have a new line. It will work. I'm currently doing exactly that for an ssh key that I'm using and it works perfectly. Using the first two line of your key as an example it would look like this `Encrypted_Key=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAyXMNDDhBf3bz60XG0FpN/nui9lfWEQkR399GZ2aXSlN/gsUf\n...`